# Margin/padding comes outside a div

Tags: html, css

I have tried to use margin/padding (top 80% / bottom 20%) to position text about 20% above the bottom of the div. However it looks like it does not work this way, the margin/padding simply comes out of box instead of positioning the text as wanted.

I can position it at the center of the image using margin: 20% but I want to position it 20% above the bottom line as elseway the text keeps on moving around when I change resolution, sometimes it hides completely due to overflow.

Any suggestions on how to align just slightly above the bottom of the div? Preferably without using position: absolute as this setting messed up everything else for me.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8h583xyx/5/)

```css
.featured_title {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 80%; /* this needs to be removed in order for text to become visible as currently it's hidden due to overflow:hidden */ 
    margin-bottom: 20%;
    font-size: 4vw;
    color: #000;
    width: 65%;
    text-align: center;
}

.browser {
  width: 1366px;
  height: 768px;
}

.featured_box {
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.banner {
    max-height: inherit;
}

.banner {
    margin:auto;
    width: 80%;
    display: block;
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.featured_image {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class=browser>
    <div class="featured_box">
        <div class="banner" onclick="location.href=">
            <div class="featured_image" style="background-image: 
 url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d1/Mount_Everest_as_seen_from_Drukair2_PLW_edit.jpg/1024px-Mount_Everest_as_seen_from_Drukair2_PLW_edit.jpg)">
                <p class="featured_title">Text goes here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class=browser>
```

Comment: Everyone, I think, couldn't understand what exactly you wanted. You said "position text about 20% above the bottom of the div", now you have 5 divs altogether. You need to specify which div? Is it "browser", "featured_box"? Than based on that see where exactly "position text about 20% above the bottom"

Comment: My apologies, 20% of the bottom line of "featured_image" div. When I say 20%, I guess we are talking 20% of total image/div height.

Comment: thanks to Ilimkan Omurzakova, the issue has been resolved. Just a quick update to what seemed to be the issue. Using margin-top: 20% instead of pixels seemed to cause the issue and text to float up and down depending on the resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying px instead of percentage in this case will fix the issues.

You can view on codepen as well - https://codepen.io/Ilima/pen/gzVWJB?editors=1100

```css
.featured_box {
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.featured_image {
    background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d1/Mount_Everest_as_seen_from_Drukair2_PLW_edit.jpg/1024px-Mount_Everest_as_seen_from_Drukair2_PLW_edit.jpg);
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
}
.featured_image:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.featured_title{
  margin-top: 360px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="featured_box">
  
  <div class="featured_image">
      <p class="featured_title"> Text goes here </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="browser"></div>
```

Comment: A very close call, thank you. However, I am looking for a "featured_title" to raise itself 20% of the bottom of "featured_image". elseway the text disappears and goes too low when a resolution is changed. I kinda want it to just stay in one position and just change in size when computer resolution is changed. I understand this can be done by playing around with @media tag, but the text still moves around and doesn't provde a desired result

Comment: You're welcome! Ok, I see. And when you open my codpen https://codepen.io/Ilima/pen/gzVWJB?editors=1100 does the text move around?

Comment: It actually doesn't move! I think this is what I was looking for, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Oful That's awesome! I hope that was helpful. By the way you can even have one div with the image and text, so the code going to be more clean and more efficient. You added 4-5 divs, and this will still work, don't take me wrong way, but if each one has it's own different values, it may have some bugs at the end in some situations.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

I added the following CSS to `.featured-image`:

```css
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: flex-end;
padding-bottom: 20%;
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.featured_title {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 4vw;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  color:white;
  
}

.browser {
  width: 1366px;
  height: 768px;
}

.featured_box {
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.banner {
  max-height: inherit;
}

.banner {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  display: block;
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.featured_image {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding-bottom: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class=browser>
  <div class="featured_box">
    <div class="banner" onclick="location.href=">
      <div class="featured_image" style="background-image: 
 url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d1/Mount_Everest_as_seen_from_Drukair2_PLW_edit.jpg/1024px-Mount_Everest_as_seen_from_Drukair2_PLW_edit.jpg)">
        <p class="featured_title">Text goes here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class=browser>
```

Comment: This is pretty close, however I was looking for a text to be inside the div, at the bottom, however without using top-padding as this then messes up due to overflow:hidden. To see what I mean, change padding-bottom: 20%; to padding-top: 35% . I hope Im being clear enough

Answer (score 2):

I have added "top" and "position" element to your code and removed margins 
Is this what you are looking for? 
I mean Text just above the div of your Image

```css
 

   * ..featured_title {
-webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    position: relative;   <!---added position -->
    top: 450px;           <!-- added top --> 
    font-size: 4vw;
    color: #000;
    width: 65%;
    text-align: center;

}

.browser {
  width: 1366px;
  height: 768px;
}

.featured_box {
    max-height: 500px;
overflow: hidden;
}

.banner {
max-height: inherit;
}

.banner {
margin:auto;
  width: 80%;
  display: block;
max-height: 500px;
overflow: hidden;
}

.featured_image {
overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
height: 500px;
width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class=browser>
  <div class="featured_box">
    <div class="banner" onclick="location.href=">
      <div class="featured_image" style="background-image: 
 url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d1/Mount_Everest_as_seen_from_Drukair2_PLW_edit.jpg/1024px-Mount_Everest_as_seen_from_Drukair2_PLW_edit.jpg)">
        <p class="featured_title">Text goes here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class=browser>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the code for you:

```
<body>

      <div class="container-fluid img-responsive">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 " ></div>
          <div class=" col-4 col-sm-4" ><img src="4.jpg"> </div>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-4 col-sm-4 " ></div>
        <div class=" col-4 col-sm-4" >text goes here</div>
       </div>
      </div>

</body>
```

you can resize the window to see responsiveness: https://jsfiddle.net/3myfa6fe/

and mind you I am using bootstrap for it .Please add the required libraries for it from CDN bootstrap page.this is a very small code understandable rather than taking up those big html css code pieces.all the best.

Comment: OP does nto indicate they are using Bootstrap; if you are going to provide one using Bootstrap that's fine, but please explicitly state that. It adds a huge overhead when used.

Comment: Bootstrap is what provides the overhead. It may be new or modern, but not everyone uses it, wants to use it, or even *can* use it.

Comment: what are you talking about latest technologies are made to make things easier!!!!!!

Comment: Not everyone uses the same technologies for things. Like I said, if you want to include a Bootstrap solution, that's fine and valid, but you should tell OP explicitly "I am using Bootstrap" because OP can't just add those classes from your code to theirs and expect it to work when they aren't using Bootstrap already.

Comment: @TylerH i have edited it now you are happy give me an upvote!!!!!!!!!!!